# Как открыть настройки звука и другие системные настройки с помощью кода?

Tags: windows, любой-язык

Не могу догнать, как открыть ванильные настройки Windows?
Хочу написать программу, которая по нажатию одной кнопки открывала бы системные настройки звука (mmsys.cpl), но после огромно количества потраченного времени на поиски информации я так её и не нашёл.
Желательно скинуть код на pHp, но подойдёт любой язык.

Comment: `Process.Start("mmsys.cpl");` - одна строка кода на C#. Аналогично во многих других языках: запустить процесс, указав путь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

джава:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mmsys.cpl");
```

питон:

```
os.system("mmsys.cpl")
```